# How to receive HTTP Post message to webserver in C#

Tags: c#

i want to know what i am posting in that URL and what message is received from web server.Because in my local server is working in HTTP Post Message and when i deploy to another server it not posted and get Error code for 400 bad request.i will check that URL string in correct and HTTP post also working.

Comment: You need to show your code / what you have tried...??

Comment: Try using fiddler to catch the requests

Comment: Your question says , you need help on `receive HTTP Post message` , but you said that `you are posting URL`, i am not clear, please explain, what you want!

Comment: i want to know what is the content received from web server and how to get that information?

Comment: Make it clear! , You have a page in web server, and that page posts content or how come webserver comes into picture?

Comment: Yes. i need that information ..

Comment: How to capture that information.